# How to correctly address / link a class in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Currently I have two classes that work together.

The Graphics class has a list that receives all Sprite classes created as in the example below:

Sprite:

```
def initialize(bitmap = nil, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, opacity = 255)
@bitmap = bitmap
@x = x
@y = y
@z = z
@opacity = opacity
@viewport = nil

@ox = 0
@oy = 0

@visible = true

Graphics.newSpr(self)
end
```

Graphics:

```
def self.newSpr(spr)
@sprites = [] if @sprites.nil?
@sprites.push(spr)
end
```

I need everything that happens with the Sprite class OUTSIDE the Graphics list to be updated in the list as well.

For example, if I run this code:

```
sprite = Sprite.new
sprite.list[1] = 1
```

In the Graphic list the value of list [1] will still be null.

Comment: What is this `list` method? You don't show where it's defined.

Comment: Note: Most Ruby styleguides strongly encourage the use of names like `new_spr` in preference to `newSpr` as variable and method names should be lower-case only.

Comment: Please get in the habit of using standard indentation in your source. It helps everyone read your code, including your future you.